# Small Files Are Transferred as Zero Bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

In my Python script, my csv files are transferred over ftp to another computer. However, it seems that when my ftp files are too small, they are transferred as zero bytes (ex: a smaller csv file shows up empty, while a larger one shows up normally). I was wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar problem, and how you fixed it?

EDIT:
My code does correctly run and create the "demo.csv" file, it just adds it as zero bytes.

```
    import ftplib

    ftp = ftplib.FTP(property_dict['ftp_server'], property_dict['ftp_username'], property_dict['ftp_passwd'])

    ftp.storbinary('STOR demo.csv', open('demo.csv', 'rb'))

    ftp.quit()
```

Comment: Share the part of script where you ftp the file.

Comment: You could add `assert len(open('demo.csv', 'rb').read(10000)) > 0` just to make sure your assumptions are correct. If you are generating the files in the same program, you may not have flushed or closed the  file so its still buffered.

Comment: Can you upload small files correctly from the same machine using any standalone FTP client?

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone, I eventually figured out I had an issue with my ftp server.